# Error in Oversampling example in R

Tags: r, random-forest, oversampling

I am runing below code for oversampling in R

```
varNames1 = paste0("Quote.Type","+","Quote.State","+","Forecast.Type","+","Suggested.Reseller.Discount","+","Territory","+","Pricing.Type")

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                                           number = 10, 
                                           repeats = 10, 
                                           verboseIter = FALSE,
                                           sampling = "up")

set.seed(42)
model_rf_under <- caret::train(renew.dev$Result ~ varNames1,
                               data = renew.dev,
                               method = "rf",
                               preProcess = c("scale", "center"),
                               trControl = ctrl)
```

This is throwing below error for me. Can anyone please help.

```
Error in model.frame.default(form = renew.dev$Result ~ varNames1, data = renew.dev,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'varNames1')
```

Comment: Hi Jaivinder, would you give us a reproducible example please ?
Because object 'renew.dev' not found.
Thanks

Comment: The construction of the formula is incorrect. Use: `as.formula(paste0("Result ~ ", varNames1 ))` instead of `renew.dev$Result ~ varNames1`.

Comment: I m in learning phase and this was valuable, Thanks @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz that worked for me.